# jQuery Toggle does not show on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I'm using jQuery slideToggle function and the media queries.

The problem is that when I resize the window to small size, the toggle links appear. Now if I click on toggle, it works fine, but when I resize the window back to large size, the hidden element still do not appear.

If I do not click on the toggle link, and resize the window back to large size, it works fine.

**Demo to see the problem:**

Please check the demo here, where you can see the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/3Jj7J/

Resize the window to small size that you see "Main Menu" link. When you click on it, you will see the toggle. Now if you resize it back to large size, the normal links will still not appear.

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bar">
    <a class="toggle" href="#">MAIN MENU</a>
</div>

<div class="nav">
    <div class="wrap">
        <ul>
            <li>Link 1</li>
             <li>Link 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bar{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
     .nav ul { 
        display: none;
    }

    .bar{
        display: block;        
    }
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var menu = jQuery('.nav .wrap > ul');       
jQuery(".toggle").click(function() {
    menu.slideToggle(500);
});
```

Comment: The problem obviously is, is that the inline style added by jQuery is overwriting your CSS rules. You could listen to the resize-event and force a new toggle if the element is hidden and the screen's width is over 500px.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add on window resize event handler :

```
var menu = jQuery('.nav .wrap > ul');       
jQuery(".toggle").click(function() {
    menu.slideToggle(500);
});  

jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){   
    if(!jQuery(".toggle").is(":visible") && !menu.is(':visible'))
    {
         menu.show();   
    }
});
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3Jj7J/1/

update: this is alternative solution (just remove inline `display` property, so it will use css rule).

```
jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){     
    if(!jQuery(".toggle").is(":visible") && !menu.is(':visible'))
    {
        menu.css({'display':''});   
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jj7J/2/)

Comment: As a note: This will call `menu.show()` on every resize event where the window's width is over 500px, [see](http://jsfiddle.net/qj3sr/).

Comment: the idea is showing `menu` when `".toggle"` is hidden. edited my answer, so `menu.show()` only called if `menu` is hidden.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However in your example, click on "main menu" link, and it toggles down. Now resize the window to large size, and then resize back to small size. The toggle items are no more hidden. Do you know how that can be fixed?

Comment: @dann Thanks a lot, but it does not seem to make any difference. Click on the Menu link in small size, increase the window and then decrease the window, you will see the menu items by default. I want to keep them hidden by default, and want to show only when click on the link. Thanks once again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user2738640, remove the `&& !menu.is(':visible')`, that will work. but as insertusernamehere suggest, `menu.css({'display':''});` will be called every resize event where the window's width is over 500px.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I did not see any visual problem with resize event being called on every window resize. What would be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've read your problem and tested it myself. Now, I've made the Link appear by doing the following:

**CSS:**

```
        #bar {
        display: none;
        color: #000000;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
         #nav ul { 
            display: none;
        }

        .bar{
            display: block;        


   }
}
```

To see for yourself (http://jsfiddle.net/hSZ7t/) What I've done is changed your CSS. Instead of you using:

```
.bar {
```

It's now:

```
#bar {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm sure you didnt understand the question. How does changing the class to an ID or changing the font color helps anything?

Comment: @user2738640 Okay, I've just edit the answer. The class wasn't needed to be changed. I've just changed the CSS. Now, It should appear the sentence "MAIN MENU".